# Best practice to improve the UITableView scroll behavior

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uitableview

I am seeing a little jerkiness when I scroll my tableview with huge data set (70 records).

I am using my own custom table view cells (sub classing UITableViewCell). I am using the "dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier" method with proper identifier. So, the only thing happening when I scroll the table view is cellForRowAtIndexPath call of my tableview controller and layoutSubViews call of my custom cell.

Any best practices to improve the UI response?

EDIT: Adding my code

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)iTableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)iIndexPath {
    NSDictionary *aDisplayData = nil;

    if (iTableView == self.searchController.searchResultsTableView && self.searchResult && [self.searchResult count] > 0 && (self.searchResult)[iIndexPath.section][iIndexPath.row]) {
        aDisplayData = (self.searchResult)[iIndexPath.section][iIndexPath.row];
    } else {
        if ((self.displayInfoList)[iIndexPath.section][iIndexPath.row])
            aDisplayData = (self.displayInfoList)[iIndexPath.section][iIndexPath.row];
        else
            return [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:nil]; //safety check
    }
    MyProjectTableViewCell *aCell = (MyProjectRequestSummaryCell *)[iTableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:kMyProjectRequestSummaryCell];

    if (!aCell) {
        aCell = [[MyProjectRequestSummaryCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:kMyProjectRequestSummaryCell];
    }

    if ([[aDisplayData stringForKey:kMyProjectCustomerNameKey] length] > 0) {
        aCell.customerNameLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [aDisplayData stringForKey:kMyProjectCustomerNameKey]];
        aCell.customerNameLabel.accessibilityLabel = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@", MyProjectLocalized(kMyProjectCustomerNameAccessibilityLabelKey),
                                                      [aDisplayData stringForKey:kMyProjectCustomerNameKey]];
        [aCell.imageView setImage:nil];
    } else {
        aCell.customerNameLabel.text = nil;
    }
    NSString *anEmployeeFirstName = [aDisplayData stringForKey:kMyProjectRequestOwnerFirstNameKey];
    NSString *anEmployeeLastName = [aDisplayData stringForKey:kMyProjectRequestOwnerLastNameKey];
    NSString *anEmployeePreferredName = [aDisplayData stringForKey:kMyProjectRequestOwnerPreferredNameKey];

    aCell.textLabel.text = [MyProjectUtilities employeeDisplayNameWithFirstName:anEmployeeFirstName lastName:anEmployeeLastName andPreferredName:anEmployeePreferredName];
    aCell.textLabel.accessibilityLabel = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@", MyProjectLocalized(kMyProjectSpecialistNameAccessibilityLabelKey),
                                          [aDisplayData stringForKey:kMyProjectRequestOwnerKey]];

    if ([[aDisplayData stringForKey:kMyProjectRequestSubTypeKey] isEqualToString:kMyProjectReverseMyProjectIdentifier] || [[aDisplayData stringForKey:kMyProjectRequestSubTypeKey] isEqualToString:kMyProjectSNRRequestIdentifier]) {
        aCell.detailTextLabel.text = [aDisplayData stringForKey:kMyProjectPickUpFromLocationNameKey];
        aCell.detailTextLabel.accessibilityLabel = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@", MyProjectLocalized(kMyProjectPickUpFromAccessibilityLabelKey),
                                                    [aDisplayData stringForKey:kMyProjectPickUpFromLocationNameKey]];
    } else {
        aCell.detailTextLabel.text = [aDisplayData stringForKey:kMyProjectDeliveryToLocationNameKey];
        aCell.detailTextLabel.accessibilityLabel = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@", MyProjectLocalized(kMyProjectDeliverToAccessibilityLabelKey),
                                                    [aDisplayData stringForKey:kMyProjectDeliveryToLocationNameKey]];
    }

    NSString *aRequestAssigneeDSID = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", [aDisplayData integerForKey:kMyProjectRequestAssigneeDSIDKey]];

    NSDictionary *aRequestDetails = @{kMyProjectRequestTypeKey : [aDisplayData stringForKey:kMyProjectRequestTypeKey], kMyProjectRequestSubTypeKey : [aDisplayData stringForKey:kMyProjectRequestSubTypeKey], kMyProjectStatusIdentifierKey : [aDisplayData stringForKey:kMyProjectStatusIdentifierKey], kMyProjectRequestAssigneeDSIDKey: aRequestAssigneeDSID};

    NSDictionary *aRequestImageDetails = [MyProjectUtilities imagesForRequestDetails:aRequestDetails];
    aCell.imageView.image = aRequestImageDetails[kMyProjectRequestImage];
    if (![MyProjectUtilities isIOS7orAbove])
        aCell.imageView.highlightedImage = aRequestImageDetails[kMyProjectRequestHighlightedImage];

    if ([[aDisplayData valueForKey:kMyProjectIsCustomerRestockingKey] boolValue]) {
        aCell.customerRestockingImage.image = [UIImage imageNamed:kMyProjectCustomerRestockingImage];
        if (![MyProjectUtilities isIOS7orAbove])
            aCell.customerRestockingImage.highlightedImage = [UIImage imageNamed:kMyProjectCustomerRestockingWhiteImage];
    } else {
        aCell.customerRestockingImage.image = nil;
        aCell.customerRestockingImage.highlightedImage = nil;
    }

    NSDictionary *aRequestStatusInfo = [MyProjectUtilities displayInfoForIdentifier:[aDisplayData stringForKey:kMyProjectStatusIdentifierKey]] ;
    NSString *aRequestStatus = MyProjectLocalized([aRequestStatusInfo stringForKey:kMyProjectLocalizationMessageKey]);
    aCell.requestStatusLabel.text = aRequestStatus;
    aCell.requestStatusLabel.accessibilityLabel = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@", MyProjectLocalized(kMyProjectRequestStatusAccessibilityLabelKey),
                                                   aRequestStatus];

    if ([[aDisplayData stringForKey:kMyProjectWebOrderNumberKey] length]) {
        aCell.webOrderNumberLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"(%@)", [aDisplayData stringForKey:kMyProjectWebOrderNumberKey]];
        aCell.webOrderNumberLabel.accessibilityLabel = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@", MyProjectLocalized(kMyProjectWebOrderNumberAccessibilityLabelKey),
                                                        [aDisplayData stringForKey:kMyProjectWebOrderNumberKey]];
    } else {
        aCell.webOrderNumberLabel.text = kMyProjectEmptyString;
    }

    aCell.timestampLabel.text = [aDisplayData stringForKey:kMyProjectElapsedTimeKey];
    aCell.timestampLabel.accessibilityLabel = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@", MyProjectLocalized(kMyProjectElapsedTimeAccessibilityLabelKey),
                                               [aDisplayData stringForKey:kMyProjectElapsedTimeKey]];
    aCell.accessibilityHint = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@", MyProjectLocalized(kMyProjectViewActionAccessibilityHintKey),
                               MyProjectLocalized(kMyProjectRequestInfoAccessibilityHintKey)];
    return aCell;
}

- (void)layoutSubviews {
    [super layoutSubviews]; 
    self.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];

    if (self.inEditMode) {
        self.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
        self.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
    } else {
        self.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleBlue;
        self.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;
    }

    CGRect aContentRect = [self.contentView bounds];

    CGFloat aTimestampLabelWidth = [self.timestampLabel.text sizeWithFont:[UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:kFontSize10]].width;
    CGFloat aSpecialistNameWidth = [self.textLabel.text sizeWithFont:[UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:kFontSize14]].width;
    CGFloat aLocationNameWidth = [self.detailTextLabel.text sizeWithFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:kFontSize12]].width;

    if (aLocationNameWidth > kRunnerLocationNameWidth) {
        aLocationNameWidth = kRunnerLocationNameWidth;
    }
    CGFloat aCustomerNameWidth = aContentRect.size.width - aLocationNameWidth - 2 * kRunnerLeftRightMargin;
    CGFloat aTextLabelHeight = kRunnerDefaultTextHeight;
    CGSize aTextLabelSize = [self.textLabel.text sizeWithFont:self.textLabel.font forWidth:aSpecialistNameWidth lineBreakMode:NSLineBreakByTruncatingTail];
    if (aTextLabelSize.height > 0) {
        aTextLabelHeight = aTextLabelSize.height;
    }

    CGFloat aDetailTextLabelHeight = kRunnerDefaultTextHeight;
    CGSize aDetailTextLabelSize = [self.detailTextLabel.text sizeWithFont:self.detailTextLabel.font forWidth:aLocationNameWidth lineBreakMode:NSLineBreakByTruncatingTail];
    if (aDetailTextLabelSize.height > 0) {
        aDetailTextLabelHeight = aDetailTextLabelSize.height;
    }

    if (self.imageView.image) {
        CGFloat aImageMargin = self.imageView.image.size.width; //Imagewidth
        self.imageView.frame = CGRectMake(aContentRect.origin.x , kScreenOrigin, self.imageView.image.size.width, self.imageView.image.size.height);
        [self.imageView centerVerticallyInSuperview];

        self.textLabel.frame = CGRectMake(aContentRect.origin.x + aImageMargin, floorf((aContentRect.size.height - aTextLabelHeight - aDetailTextLabelHeight - kRunnerDefaultTextHeight) / 2), aContentRect.size.width - (aContentRect.origin.x + aImageMargin + kRunnerLeftRightMargin), aTextLabelHeight);
        self.detailTextLabel.frame = CGRectMake(aContentRect.origin.x + aImageMargin , self.textLabel.frame.origin.y + aTextLabelHeight, aLocationNameWidth, aDetailTextLabelHeight);
        self.requestStatusLabel.frame = CGRectMake(aContentRect.origin.x + aImageMargin, self.detailTextLabel.frame.origin.y + aDetailTextLabelHeight, aContentRect.size.width - aImageMargin - aTimestampLabelWidth - 18.0f, kRunnerDefaultTextHeight);
        self.customerNameLabel.frame = CGRectMake(aContentRect.size.width - aCustomerNameWidth - 8.0f + aImageMargin, self.textLabel.frame.origin.y + aTextLabelHeight, (aCustomerNameWidth - aImageMargin), kRunnerDefaultTextHeight);

        if (self.webOrderNumberLabel.text) {
            self.webOrderNumberLabel.frame = CGRectMake(aContentRect.origin.x + [self.requestStatusLabel.text sizeWithFont:[UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:kFontSize12]].width + aImageMargin, self.detailTextLabel.frame.origin.y + kRunnerDefaultTextHeight, kRunnerDefaultTextWidth / 2, kRunnerDefaultTextHeight);

          if (aImageMargin && self.requestStatusLabel.text && self.timestampLabel.text) //width check
          {

              if ((aImageMargin + [self.webOrderNumberLabel.text sizeWithFont:[UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:kFontSize14]].width + [self.requestStatusLabel.text sizeWithFont:[UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:kFontSize12]].width + [self.timestampLabel.text sizeWithFont:[UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:kFontSize12]].width + kRunnerLeftRightMargin) > aContentRect.size.width)
              {
                  self.webOrderNumberLabel.font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:kFontSize12];   
              }
          }
        }

        if (self.customerRestockingImage.image) {
            self.textLabel.frame = CGRectMake(aContentRect.origin.x + aImageMargin, floorf((aContentRect.size.height - aTextLabelHeight - aDetailTextLabelHeight - kRunnerDefaultTextHeight) / 2), aContentRect.size.width - (aContentRect.origin.x + aImageMargin + kRunnerLeftRightMargin + self.customerRestockingImage.image.size.width), aTextLabelHeight);
            self.customerRestockingImage.frame =  CGRectMake(self.textLabel.frame.origin.x + self.textLabel.frame.size.width, self.textLabel.frame.origin.y, self.customerRestockingImage.image.size.width, self.customerRestockingImage.image.size.width);
        }
    } else {
        self.imageView.frame = CGRectZero;
        self.customerRestockingImage.frame = CGRectZero;
        self.textLabel.frame = CGRectMake(aContentRect.origin.x + kRunnerLeftRightMargin, floorf((aContentRect.size.height - aTextLabelHeight - aDetailTextLabelHeight - kRunnerDefaultTextHeight) / 2), aSpecialistNameWidth, aTextLabelHeight);
        self.detailTextLabel.frame = CGRectMake(aContentRect.origin.x + kRunnerLeftRightMargin, self.textLabel.frame.origin.y + aTextLabelHeight, aLocationNameWidth, aDetailTextLabelHeight);
        self.requestStatusLabel.frame = CGRectMake(aContentRect.origin.x + kRunnerLeftRightMargin, self.detailTextLabel.frame.origin.y + aDetailTextLabelHeight, aContentRect.size.width - aTimestampLabelWidth - 18.0f, kRunnerDefaultTextHeight);
        self.customerNameLabel.frame = CGRectMake(aContentRect.size.width - aCustomerNameWidth - 8.0f, floorf((aContentRect.size.height / 2.0f) - (kRunnerDefaultTextHeight / 2.0f)), aCustomerNameWidth, kRunnerDefaultTextHeight);

        if (self.webOrderNumberLabel.text) {
            self.webOrderNumberLabel.frame = CGRectMake(aContentRect.origin.x + kRunnerLeftRightMargin + [self.requestStatusLabel.text sizeWithFont:[UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:kFontSize12]].width, self.detailTextLabel.frame.origin.y + kRunnerDefaultTextHeight, kRunnerDefaultTextWidth, kRunnerDefaultTextHeight);
        }
    }

    self.timestampLabel.frame = CGRectMake(aContentRect.size.width - aTimestampLabelWidth - 18.0f, self.requestStatusLabel.frame.origin.y, aTimestampLabelWidth + 10, kRunnerDefaultTextHeight);
    self.timestampLabel.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentRight;
    self.customerNameLabel.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentRight;
    self.customerNameLabel.font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:kFontSize12];

    self.textLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    self.detailTextLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    self.requestStatusLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    self.customerNameLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    self.webOrderNumberLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    self.timestampLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];

}
```

Comment: If you can it would help if you posted your code, especially the 2 methods you've mentioned. I wouldn't say 70 is a huge data set

Comment: If you're using images inside cells, and if you're not loading them asynchronously, it might cause that jerkiness.

Comment: @Piyuesh totally correct on that. Lazy loading of images solves that problem.

Comment: also avoid "clip to bounds = YES" for any subview/image view/label etc in your custom cell

Comment: Also consider the device that you are using for test, I have found iPhone 4 to be the slowest (in terms of graphics rendering performance) but 3gs, 5 and 5s are much faster. It may be acceptable if it only affects iPhone 4.

Comment: I have images on my custom cells but they are all part of the bundle and I am not fetching them from server.

Comment: Are you sure to use dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier properly? what happens if you set a breakpoint at cell init, does it stop for each cell ?

Comment: What really slows down scrolling is file I/O. Make sure that you have none of that in cellForRowAtIndexPath

Comment: Not sure How badly this would affect performance but try avoid using a clear colour on Labels.

Comment: @Justafinger : dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier is being used properly and I have double checked it.

Comment: @Eyeball : What do you mean by file I/O here?

Comment: Do you realize layoutSubview is called for every single cell each time it is displayed? Most of your code could probably go in your MyProjectRequestSummaryCell init where it will be called only for the first cells.